# Get envelope (or boundary) of overlapping latitude longitude domains

Tags: python, gis, shapely

I have a number of longitude, latitude grid domains which are overlapping. Now, I need to plot the "outer line" around those domains but I can't find a proper solution for that. All of this needs to be done in python, where I am doing the data handling and plotting of fields (a composite of values from different grid domains).
I know this can be achieved with postgresql+postgis by somehow intersecting the domain boundaries, but I don't want to involve databases just for this issue.

A convex hull is not what I am looking for, as this will not cover "the concave part of the problem". 
Alpha shapes are - in my opinion - also not the right way to go as these do not provide a well defined solution. Apparently it all depends on the alpha value chosen. Examples found e.g. here: http://blog.thehumangeo.com/2014/05/12/drawing-boundaries-in-python/

I think the problem must have a well defined single solution, as i am just looking for the intersection of some lines defined through lon/lat points.

Now, to make it clearer, here is an artificial example, where I create just two domains, join them to get an array of lon/lat points for all (two) domains and try a few things with shapely (as this seemed most promising):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint, Polygon

#two sample domains of longitudes and latitudes
dom1 = np.array([np.linspace(12.0,19.0,20), np.linspace(41.0,42.0,20)])
dom1 = np.append(dom1, [np.linspace(19.0,19.5,20), np.linspace(42.0,32.0,20)],axis=1)
dom1 = np.append(dom1, [np.linspace(19.5,11.5,20), np.linspace(32.0,31.0,20)],axis=1)
dom1 = np.append(dom1, [np.linspace(11.5,12.0,20), np.linspace(31.0,41.0,20)],axis=1)

dom2 = np.array([np.linspace(14.0,21.0,20), np.linspace(44.0,44.5,20)])
dom2 = np.append(dom2, [np.linspace(21.0,19.5,20), np.linspace(44.5,35.0,20)],axis=1)
dom2 = np.append(dom2, [np.linspace(19.5,14.,20), np.linspace(35.0,35.2,20)],axis=1)
dom2 = np.append(dom2, [np.linspace(14.,14.,20), np.linspace(35.2,44.0,20)],axis=1)

plt.plot(dom1[0,:],dom1[1,:],'k')
plt.plot(dom2[0,:],dom2[1,:],'r')         
plt.show()
```

The figure below shows the two sample domains overlapping. I am now interested in the set of points building "the outer boundary" of the two domains (i.e. if one would walk (clock-wise) along the domain boundary and always turn left at intersections).
[image: Plot of the two domains]

```
#join the domains in one array
doms = np.hstack([dom1,dom2])

#convex hull
points = MultiPoint(zip(doms[0,:],doms[1,:]))
x,y = points.convex_hull.exterior.xy

plt.plot(doms[0,:],doms[1,:],'k.')
plt.plot(x,y,'ro-')
plt.show()
```

The convex hull is missing the "inner" parts and is not the desired solution:
[image: Convex hull is missing the inner part]

```
#polygon boundary
poly = Polygon(zip(doms[0,:],doms[1,:]))
x1,y1 = poly.boundary.xy
plt.plot(doms[0,:],doms[1,:],'k.')
plt.plot(x1,y1,'go-')
plt.show()
```

Experimenting with polygon boundary does also not yield anything useful:
[image]

Can shapely be used to solve this problem?
Or are there any other gis-related packages that could help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to me that what you are after is the exterior boundary of the union of the two polygons:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint, Polygon

#two sample domains of longitudes and latitudes
dom1 = np.array([np.linspace(12.0,19.0,20), np.linspace(41.0,42.0,20)])
dom1 = np.append(dom1, [np.linspace(19.0,19.5,20), np.linspace(42.0,32.0,20)],axis=1)
dom1 = np.append(dom1, [np.linspace(19.5,11.5,20), np.linspace(32.0,31.0,20)],axis=1)
dom1 = np.append(dom1, [np.linspace(11.5,12.0,20), np.linspace(31.0,41.0,20)],axis=1)

dom2 = np.array([np.linspace(14.0,21.0,20), np.linspace(44.0,44.5,20)])
dom2 = np.append(dom2, [np.linspace(21.0,19.5,20), np.linspace(44.5,35.0,20)],axis=1)
dom2 = np.append(dom2, [np.linspace(19.5,14.,20), np.linspace(35.0,35.2,20)],axis=1)
dom2 = np.append(dom2, [np.linspace(14.,14.,20), np.linspace(35.2,44.0,20)],axis=1)

P = Polygon(dom1.T)
Q = Polygon(dom2.T)
P = P.union(Q)

dom3 = np.asarray(P.exterior.coords).T

plt.plot(dom1[0,:],dom1[1,:],'k')
plt.plot(dom2[0,:],dom2[1,:],'r')         
plt.plot(dom3[0,:],dom3[1,:],'go-')         
plt.show()
```

[image]